# SSIS:I need to apply fuzzy lookup on multiple table columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, powerbi, ssas

I need to apply fuzzy lookup on multiple table columns. for example - I have table A which contains 4 columns(50% matched data ) which look 4 different tables which contain 100% matched data. I want to apply fuzzy lookup on 4 different data sets which match data from different 4 tables and give me correct data for table A. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

In the edit querys go to `Merge Querys > Merge As New` and check the `Use fuzzy matching to compare the merge` in the pane (You also have some fuzzy merge options here for example the match percentage) and hit OK.

If you have more tables to match with, just repeat the first step again on the newly created table.

You can also pass a transformation table where you cen specify some matching criterias.

Comment: Thanks ..i am new for SSIS so can you tell me where I find this edit query option in ssis.

Comment: This option doesnt exist in SSRS as far as I know. But it does in Power BI.